# smooth bijective functon's derivative $\ne 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$f\colon (\alpha,\beta)\to (a,b)$ is a smooth bijective functon, that is, the derivative $f^{(n)}(x)$ exists for all $n\ge 1$.

1) If the inverse function $f^{-1}\colon (a,b)\to (\alpha,\beta)$ is also smooth, does it follow that the derivative $f^\prime(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in (\alpha,\beta)$?

2) If the derivative $f^\prime(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in (\alpha,\beta)$,  Can we conclude that 
the inverse function $f^{-1}$ is also smooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and Yes.

The first one follows from chain rule: $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ for all $x\in (a, b)$ implies
$$\frac{df^{-1}}{dx}(f(x)) \cdot \frac{df}{dx}(x) = 1 \Rightarrow \frac{df}{dx}(x)\neq 0\ .$$

For the second one, it follows from the inverse function theorem.

The two results are true in any dimensions.